# React effect that changes state and depends on state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React app that displays stock quotes, the user can add and remove stocks from the list etc. I have an effect to fetch the prices, since it depends on the quotes array, when I add a new quote it'll run the fetch manually. But I also want the prices to be continually updated after a short interval....roughly like below :

```
function StockApp() {

  const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState([]);
  // an entry in the quotes array is an object like below
  // They come like this straight from the backend which returns
  // a simple JSON format
  // {
  //   symbol: 'MSFT',
  //   price: 298.12
  //   dayChange: 1.2
  // }

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(async () => {
      const newQuotes = await fetchPrices(quotes);
      // this will be a new array
      setQuotes(newQuotes);
    }, TICKER_REFRESH_INTERVAL);

    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [quotes]);


  ... render function etc
```

Although the app works fine, my query is about the recursive nature of my useEffect function....as I understand it I'm saying here "Whenever quotes changes, run the function" but the effect function is also changing quotes, it seems like the setTimeout prevents it recursing.  I feel like I am not thinking about the problem in the correct way, how can I avoid this cyclic dependency ? Do I need to ?

Comment: I have a bunch of thoughts on this one but just one thing worth noting is that since your useEffect runs every time `quotes` is changed, you can switch your `setInterval` to `setTimeout` and you'll achieve the same effect. This is because your `setInterval` will run once, change `quotes`, clean up, then re-run.

Comment: An example of what I mean about using `setTimeout`: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-pare-8lzkz?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: @JamieDixon - yes indeed that does work, makes sense - i've updated it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think this approach is mostly fine. It's not recursive - as you've pointed out - because of the `setTimeout`. As a personal preference I'd abstract this out into something that can be `subscribe`d to and use `useEffect` to set up the subscription. Similarly to how it's working now, the subscription would be unsubscribed and re-subscribed when the user makes changes to the dependency.

Comment: I've put together an example of how this might look using observables that can be subscribed to. Even if this isn't something you're keen on, it might spark some ideas. Notice how the `useEffect` here only re-subscribes when a new ticker ID is added by the user. https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-pare-8lzkz?file=/src/WithSub.tsx